# Search and replace a sequence of characters in emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

I am using Emacs, and I have a file with some strings like this..

```
IMPORTED_DATA_K_NAME
IMPORTED_DATA_L_PHONE
IMPORTED_DATA_M_URL
```

I want to change the contents to ..

```
IMPORTED_DATA_A_NAME
IMPORTED_DATA_B_PHONE
IMPORTED_DATA_C_URL
```

Basically change `_K_ to _A_` and `_L_ to _B_` and so on..

This is a rather large file with lot of repetitions. I was looking at query-replace-regex but was not sure if that accomplishes this or is there a better way to accomplish this change.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your desired output is unclear, do you want the new letters to always be the next letter in the alphabet? What happens if the input is more than 26 lines?

Comment: Not the next letter.. it needs to start from 'A' as in ASCII 65. so _K_ is always _A_ and _L_ is always _B_ etc..

Comment: I still dont see your pattern. Do you want the ascii value of the input - 10? What happens if your input has IMPORTED_DATA_A_NAME?

Comment: The data pattern is only till _Z_ .

I am looking to find K with the underscores and then replace with A with the same underscores..

Comment: So all you want to do is **[Ceasar Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)** of 12 characters. Right ?

Comment: Yep.. that is correct..

Comment: 10 characters isnt it?

Comment: Yes.. K to Z replaced with A to Q

Answer (score 0):

`C-M-%` or `M-x query-replace-regexp` with the regexp `_\([K-Z]\)_` and the replacement `_\,(char-to-string (- (string-to-char \1) 10))_`.  `\,(expr)` in the replacement evaluates `(expr)` as lisp.